# How to create a url variable with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The function myClick is used to download a file from the internet to the PC that is running the app.
I want to be able to change the url that is used for downloading the file from time to time without updating the application on every single pc that is running the app

```
def myClick():

filename = Path.home() / "Desktop" / "AccountintApp.xlsm"
url = 'https://xxxxxxxxx.mediafire.com/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/AccountingApp.xlsm'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, myfile)
os.startfile(myfile)
```

I have thought of the following way to do so but I don't know how to write them in code.

```
def myClick
url_link = (a line that make access to an online google sheet for example where the download link is stored where I can change the url easily)

filename = Path.home() / "Desktop" / "AccountintApp.xlsm"
url = (url_link)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, myfile)
os.startfile(myfile)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest adding an input field for your new URL to the GUI window. After pressing the control button, verify that this input field is empty. If this input field is not empty, use the value of this input field as the new url.

Comment: as the previous commenter mentioned I would also suggest adding it in sort of a hidden manner and also save to a file

Answer (score 0):

So I made some code to add a menu where it would be possible to change the url and then it would save that to a file (the code is more of an idea of how that might be done):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Menu, Toplevel, Label, Entry, Button, Frame, StringVar, PhotoImage
import json


try:
    with open('settings.json') as file:
        settings_data = json.load(file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open('settings.json', 'w') as file:
        to_dump = {'url': None}
        json.dump(to_dump, file, indent=2)
    with open('settings.json') as file:
        settings_data = json.load(file)


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('700x500')
        self.menu_bar = Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

        self.menu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.menu)

        self.menu.add_command(label='Settings', command=self.show_options)

    def show_options(self):
        settings = Settings(self)
        settings.focus_force()


class Settings(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.geometry(f'700x500+{self.parent.winfo_rootx()}+{self.parent.winfo_rooty()}')
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.close)
        self.config(bg='grey20')

        self.settings = settings_data

        # url settings -------------------------------------------------------
        self.url_frame = Frame(self, bg='grey20', relief='sunken', bd=3)
        self.url_frame.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10, pady=10)

        Label(self.url_frame, text='Uniform Resource Locator', bg='grey20',
              fg='white', font='default 10 normal').pack(side='top')

        self.url_var = StringVar(value=self.settings['url'])
        self.current_url = Label(self.url_frame, textvariable=self.url_var, wraplength=600,
                                 anchor='w', bg='grey20', fg='white', font='default 12 normal')
        self.current_url.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5, expand=True, fill='x')

        self.url_edit_btn = Button(self.url_frame, text='Edit', width=5,
                                   command=self.edit_url, bg='grey20', fg='white',
                                   activebackground='grey30', activeforeground='white')
        self.url_edit_btn.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.edit_url_entry = Entry(self.url_frame, justify='left', bg='grey20', fg='white',
                                    font='default 12 normal', selectbackground='white',
                                    selectforeground='grey20')
        self.url_save_changes_btn = Button(self.url_frame, text='Save', width=5,
                                           command=lambda: self.url_changes('save'), bg='grey20', fg='white',
                                           activebackground='grey30', activeforeground='white')
        self.url_cancel_changes_btn = Button(self.url_frame, text='Cancel', width=5,
                                             command=lambda: self.url_changes('discard'), bg='grey20', fg='white',
                                             activebackground='grey30', activeforeground='white')
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def save_settings(self):
        with open('settings.json', 'w') as file_:
            json.dump(self.settings, file_, indent=2)

    def close(self, event):
        if event.widget == self:
            self.destroy()

    def edit_url(self):
        self.current_url.pack_forget()
        self.url_edit_btn.pack_forget()

        self.edit_url_entry.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5, expand=True, fill='x')
        self.url_cancel_changes_btn.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.url_save_changes_btn.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.edit_url_entry.insert(0, self.url_var.get())
        self.edit_url_entry.selection_range(0, 'end')
        self.edit_url_entry.focus_set()

    def url_changes(self, to_do):
        if to_do == 'save':
            url = self.edit_url_entry.get()
            self.settings['url'] = url
            self.url_var.set(url)
            self.save_settings()
        self.edit_url_entry.pack_forget()
        self.url_cancel_changes_btn.pack_forget()
        self.url_save_changes_btn.pack_forget()

        self.current_url.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5, expand=True, fill='x')
        self.url_edit_btn.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)


root = MainWindow()
pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Gonna quickly walk You through:

first import all the necessary stuff

try opening the settings file if it doesn't exist or is not found create a new one add a dictionary to it (can add more setting if needed currently just the url) and open the newly created

create the MainWindow which will just basically have the menu and that is it (simple Menu stuff) and also a function to call the settings window

defining `Settings`:

First it inherits from Toplevel so that it is easier to create the window.

set all the basic stuff and bind to `'<FocusOut>'` so that it destroys the window so no more than one window can be created (because it will destroy before calling another one).

just set the setting data to self attribute for simplicity

setting up the settings window, just some styling (not important to functionality)

first few widgets are for current display and the edit button makes url editable. it puts an Entry in place of url and allows to enter a new one, clicking on save will save the url to file, clicking cancel will do nothing except return to previous state.

the file will be created in the current directory and You can change the url whenever You need without hardcoding it.

If You have questions ask them.